# Mixing ZK 6 and Jquery UI components?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, zk

Does anyone have an idea how to integrate JQuery UI with the ZK framework (ZKOSS)?
I have tried to build a new component from the Maven archetype but it does not seem obvious to me.

Does anyone know a tutorial or can anyone give me some ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure why you were down-voted. Probably because you didn't ask a specific question and/or provided your code snippets. Please add any specific implementation that you have wrote for this to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to use JQuery UI widget in ZK

1. Wrap it as a ZK component. Use ZK client-side API to convert your JQuery UI Widget as a ZK component Widget. That way you can handle it on client side as well as on server side. Refer to [this](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2010/December/How_to_Wrap_a_jQuery_UI_Widget) article for more details
2. Simply use it on the client-side with help of ZK client-side programming as described [here](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2009/July/ZK_5.0_and_jQuery_part_2)

For more generic guidelines on using 3rd party Javascript libraries refer to [this smalltalk](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2012/November/Integrate_3rd_Party_Javascript_Libraries_In_ZK)